# Why does Chrome change inputs/select boxes in device mode?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Having this 'problem' since some time in Chrome (even on v51). After enabling the device toolbar the select boxes and submit buttons lose their styling and just show text. Using an empty fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qmfws6mq/

```html
<select>
<option>Option 1</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="test" value="Text box">
<input type="submit" value="Submit button">
```

If you can't reproduce the problem, here are two screenshots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXEe1.jpg
This happens on at least two of my computers (but only on chrome).

How does this work? Is this a bug?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on v50 or v51 on Windows. Your screenshot suggests that you are not on Windows. Does the same problem occur in e.g. Firefox?

Comment: I can reproduce this problem on OSX 10.11.4

Comment: @BramVanroy, forgot to mention this is on a Mac (10.11.5). This does not happen in Firefox or other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a new temporary style (within the browser) for inputs, that adds the missing borders.

While inspecting elements, the Styles panel allows the creation of a custom style (as shown in the screen below):

Create a style that puts a border on those inputs which will resolve the issue at least in a temporary state:

```
input {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]